# How can I mock "import pyspark" statement in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

My python script with "import pyspark" import failed saying "could not find pyspark module".
My code deployment is required to pass through Sonar scan and pyspark module name not listed in our enterprise level artifacts portal and hence the fail.

Can someone please help me understand how can I mock import statement to get out of this issue

thanks in advance.

I have mocked all calls to pyspark API which I am using in my code. But I am not aware of how to mock import statements

Comment: pip install pyspark

Comment: What is "Sonar scan"?

Comment: Don't mock the import: talk to whoever manages Sonar to *make* `pyspark` available.

Comment: @chepner- Yes, created ticket with our Jules support team. Meanwhile, my below solution worked for me. thank you

Comment: @John Gordon- Do scans on source code, including code coverage scan, usually part of CI/CD pipeline and scans the code on almost virtual environment(on the fly) during code deployments.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got this resolved. `sys.modules` list helped me.

```py
import sys

sys.modules['pyspark'] = dummy_spark_implementation()
```

I've put this statement in my unit test script just before the import statement of my main script (the script to be tested) and it worked for me.